# LibreOffice clipboard incosistencies, what gives?

Tags: libreoffice, clipboard

I've been having a pretty unusual situation with LibreOffice for quite some time, and it's been difficult to pin down the cause. Here's what happens:

- I copy some text in Writer or a slide in Impress.
- I then attempt to paste, but nothing happens.
- Then, I try copying again, and pasting again, and it works.
- Sometimes, copying twice before pasting works, other times, it doesn't.

It isn't related to using a clipboard manager, as disabling it doesn't change this behaviour. If I remember correctly, this only happens Gnome and KDE, and only sometimes. I have to do some further investigation, before I report a bug, but I wanted to know if this could be related to something else before I take that step.

Does this happen to anyone else, and if yes, what causes it?

Comment: You could mention the version and whether you've seen this issue with previous versions. I can't recollect facing this problem in any version of LibreOffice Writer or Calc, the two components I use regularly.

Comment: I have the same issue with libreoffice and with office 2010 under wine. It is extremely annoying. Using gnome-Xorg

Comment: @DKBose it's been happening for several releases. I just haven't bothered to seek a solution because I'm usually too busy.